# Robot structure kit or materials

Tags: arduino, kit

I have an arduino, wires, resistors, all of that good stuff. However, I don't have materials to build the structure of the robot. What do you guys recommend? I don't have a place to solder yet so I can't solder but is there a kit or material that you guys recommend? Will it work well with motors and other stuff? Thanks!

P.S. I plan on building a standard driving robot, but I want to be able to make other robots with the same materials/kit. I don't want a kit that only makes one robot, I want a Lego-esque approach to building the structure where I can build whatever I want with it. (Bump2)

Comment: Welcome to Robotics.SE - as things stand, this question looks like a Shopping Question and liable for closure as Opinion (https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/210/37) - perhaps you could expand your question detailing what research you have already done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vex robotics platform has many structural pieces you can use to build a robot.  It is basically the same as an old school erector set.  It also contains motors and sensors that you could interface with your Arduino.

The most important part is that it has motor controllers so that you can control the motor.  With a standard Arduino you can not drive a motor directly because it would not be able to handle the current.

http://www.vexrobotics.com/vex/products/